# Octopus Deployment to IIS Pool

Tags: iis, iis-6, octopus

So I've got a scenario where numerous different teams are deploying with octopus to local team boxes. Octopus is used to make the deployment. However I'm facing a problem where octopus is deploying to a separate drive to our IIS pool for our web apps.

Is it possible to set IIS to be configured for the alternative path without disrupting the other applications in the pool. It's not an option to change the deployment location as it would disrupt other groups. Because at the moment we're forced to copy it to the correct location after it deploys to the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

If you are packaging for msdeploy zip file, you should use common msdeploy options. You should add your octopus project iisapplicationname parameter and give it the specificied pool name with environment names. it will be deployed to the correct folders.